# How do I activate middle-click to close browser tab?

Tags: mouse

How do I configure FF or Chrome to close a tab when I middle click on it?

(I'm in the midst of migrating to OSX from linux)

Comment: Is your mouse set to use middle click on the wheel in system preferences?

Comment: The mouse settings are not active - I'm using synergy.  I hate the acceleration model mac uses, so my keyboard and mouse are connected to an old linux desktop.  Might that be causing this to not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to using synergy - when I plug my mouse in directly, it works as expected.